# Run button for Netbeans GUI is greyed out

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-8

My change calculator GUI program on Netbeans 8.0 ran when I first wrote it, but after copying the file from my desktop onto my laptop, the Run File button is greyed out. Any ideas on how to get it to run again?

Here's the code:

```
package changecalculator;


public class CoinChange extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Variablezs

 int centsAmount, cents, nickels, dimes, quarters;



 //Checking for button clicks


    public CoinChange() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton0 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        clear = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        calculateChange = new javax.swing.JButton();
        display = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        display2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 51));

        jButton0.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton0.setText("0");
        jButton0.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton0.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton0ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        clear.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        clear.setText("CLEAR");
        clear.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        clear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                clearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton7.setText("7");
        jButton7.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton8.setText("8");
        jButton8.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton9.setText("9");
        jButton9.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("4");
        jButton4.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("5");
        jButton5.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setText("6");
        jButton6.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("1");
        jButton1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("2");
        jButton2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("3");
        jButton3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        calculateChange.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        calculateChange.setText("Calculate Change");
        calculateChange.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        calculateChange.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calculateChangeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setAutoscrolls(false);
        display.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
        display.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                displayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        display2.setEditable(false);
        display2.setColumns(20);
        display2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 17)); // NOI18N
        display2.setRows(5);
        display2.setText("Please enter an amount of \nmoney in cents that is less than \n100:");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(display2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 274, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(calculateChange, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(display)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(0, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                                        .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(105, 105, 105)
                                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jButton0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(clear, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 169, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(display, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(calculateChange, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(clear, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void clearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   display.setText("");
    }                                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    display.setText(display.getText()+jButton1.getText());

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton2.getText());

    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton3.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton4.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton5.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton6.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton7.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton8.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton9.getText());
    }                                        

    private void jButton0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     display.setText(display.getText()+jButton0.getText());
    }                                        

    private void calculateChangeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    centsAmount = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(display.getText())));

  quarters = centsAmount/25;
  dimes = (centsAmount-quarters*25)/10;
  nickels = ((centsAmount%25)%10)/5;
  cents = (centsAmount%10)%5;

  while (centsAmount >= 100 || centsAmount < 1){
    //display2.setText("");
    display2.setText("Please enter an amount in cents that is less than 100 and is greater than 0:");
//Making sure that the amount entered is less than 100 and greater than 0.
    centsAmount = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(display.getText())));
//Asking the user to try again.
  quarters = centsAmount/25;
  dimes = (centsAmount-quarters*25)/10;
  nickels = ((centsAmount%25)%10)/5;
  cents = (centsAmount%10)%5;
//Recalculating
  }


display2.setText(centsAmount + " cents: ");
//First printing out the amount entered

//QUARTERS
    if (quarters > 1 && (dimes != 0 || nickels != 0 || cents != 0)){
    display2.setText(quarters + " quarters, ");
//Printing out "quarters," if the number of quarters is greater than 1 and it's not the last coin to be displayed.
}
    else if (quarters > 1 && dimes == 0 && nickels == 0 && cents == 0){
    display2.setText(quarters + " quarters.");
//Printing out "quarters." if the number of quarters is greater than 1 and it's the only coin to be displayed.
    }

    else if (quarters == 1 && (dimes != 0 || nickels != 0 || cents != 0)){
    display2.setText(quarters + " quarter, ");
//Printing out "quarter," if there is only 1 quarter and it's not the last coin to be displayed.
   }
    else if (quarters == 1 && dimes == 0 && nickels == 0 && cents == 0){
      display2.setText(quarters + " quarter.");
//Printing out "quarter." if there is only 1 quarter and it's the only coin to be displayed.
   }

//THIS REPEATS FOR THE REST OF THE COINS  

//DIMES
if (dimes > 1 && (nickels != 0 || cents != 0)){
    display2.setText(dimes + " dimes,");
  }
  else if (dimes > 1 && nickels == 0 && cents == 0 && quarters!=0){
      display2.setText(" and " + dimes + " dimes.");
    }
  else if (dimes > 1 && quarters == 0){
    display2.setText(dimes + " dimes.");
//Printing out "dimes." if the number of dimes is greater than 1 and it's the only coin displayed.
  }    
  else if (dimes == 1 && (nickels != 0 || cents != 0)){
      display2.setText(dimes + " dime,");
  }
  else if (dimes == 1 && nickels == 0 && cents == 0 && quarters!=0){
      display2.setText(" and " + dimes + " dime.");
  }
  else if (dimes == 1 && quarters == 0){
    display2.setText(dimes + " dime.");
//Printing out "dime." if there is 1 dime and it's the only coin displayed.
  }

//NICKELS
if (nickels > 1 && cents !=0){
    display2.setText(nickels + " nickels,");
  }
  else if (nickels > 1 && cents == 0){
      display2.setText("and " + nickels + " nickels.");
   }

   else if (nickels == 1 && cents !=0){

      display2.setText(nickels + " nickel,");
  }
   else if (nickels == 1 && (quarters !=0 || dimes!=0 ) && cents == 0){
      display2.setText("and " + nickels + " nickel.");
  }
   else if (nickels == 1 && quarters == 0 && dimes == 0){
     display2.setText(nickels + " nickel.");
//Printing "nickel." when it's the only coin to be displayed. There can only be 1 nickel, as 2 nickels make a dime.
   }

//CENTS    
if (cents > 1 && (quarters != 0 || dimes != 0 || nickels != 0)){
    display2.setText(" and " + cents + " cents. ");
  }
   else if (cents == 1 && (quarters != 0 || dimes != 0 || nickels != 0)){
      display2.setText(" and " + cents + " cent. ");
  }
   else if (cents >1 && quarters == 0 && dimes == 0 && nickels == 0){
     display2.setText(cents + " cents.");
   }
   else if (cents == 1 && quarters == 0 && dimes == 0 && nickels == 0){
    display2.setText(cents + " cent.");

}
    }                                               

    private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CoinChange.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CoinChange.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CoinChange.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CoinChange.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CoinChange().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton calculateChange;
    private javax.swing.JButton clear;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField display;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea display2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton0;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: seems to be a known bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242261

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to copy the *file*, you need to *copy the **project***. The project (that's the directory where the `nbproject` dir is), contains informations required to run it.